# How to conditional copy unique values only?

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I want to copy unique values over to my destination worksheet but I'm getting an error with my Range. Originally I wrote a RemoveDuplicates code with exact same Range values and it worked perfectly fine. I'm assuming the issue is in my AdvancedFilter line but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

**Edit;**
I qualified my ranges and that fixed the issue(updated code). Now I realize that I need at least 2 source rows to filter from. I'm thinking I ditch using AdvancedFilter and try a different approach. Is there a way for me to use the Unique parameter or something similar without AdvancedFilter?

```vb
Private Sub moveData()
    
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        Dim wksDestination As Worksheet

        Dim lastColumn As Integer
        Dim lastRow As Integer
        Dim destinationRow As Integer

        Set wksData = Worksheets("ProspectiveCandidates")
        Set wksDestination = Worksheets("Active Candidate Information")
 
        destinationRow = 2

        lastColumn = wksData.Range("B" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = wksData.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1    'go 'up' the worksheet
            If wksData.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Move Forward" Then      'check for Move Forward Value in the current row
                'if TRUE, copy row to wksDestination and filter for Unique
                wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(i, 2), wksData.Cells(i, 5)).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=wksDestination.Range(wksDestination.Cells(destinationRow, 2), wksDestination.Cells(destinationRow, 5)), _
                Unique:=True

                'increment the output row
                destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
                
            End If
        Next i 
    End Sub
```

***Edit2;***
I updated my For loop and took out AdvancedFilter. I'm having trouble skipping over duplicates and pasting copied values once no duplicates have been detected.

```
        For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1    'go 'up' the worksheet
            If wksData.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Move Forward" Then      'check for Move Forward Value in the current row
                'if TRUE, copy cells column 2-5 in row i
                wksData.Activate
                wksData.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
            'check for duplicates on wksDestination
            For Each xlCell In xlRange
                If xlCell.Value = wksData.Cells(i, 2) Then Exit For
            Next xlCell
            
            'if no duplicates detected then paste values
            wksDestination.Activate
            wksDestination.Range(Cells(destinationRow, 2), Cells(destinationRow, 5)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'increment the output row
            destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
                
            End If
        Next i
```

***Edit3***
Here is a partial screenshot of my sheet with the source data:
[ProspectiveCandidates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvRTv.png)

When the status is updated to "Move Forward", I want just the "Candidate Name", "Source", "Team", and "Level" to be copied over to my second sheet("Active Candidate Information").

For this to run automatically, in the sheet code I have

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Run "Module3.moveData"
End Sub
```

I want to make sure that anytime new values are copied over that they go to the next empty row. I was having issues with an earlier code that would rewrite and mess up the order of my data.

Comment: `wksDestination.Range(Cells(destinationRow, 2), Cells(destinationRow, 5))` here `Cells` refers by default to the active sheet, which will throw an error if that's not the same sheet as `wksDestination`  Try `wksDestination.Cells(destinationRow, 2).Resize(1, 4)` which is a slightly simpler way to refer to the same range.

Comment: Other option to Tim's fix... qualify your ranges, e.g., `With wksData` using `.Cells()` and `.Range()`.

Comment: Qualifying my range fixed the issue but now I'm getting an error stating I need at least 2 source rows to filter from. 
I'm not sure how to work around that with what I want to do. I only want to copy values from columns 2-5 given a conditional criteria that is in column 8.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your source data (scrubbed for sensitive info as appropriate) so we can get a clearer idea of what you want to do?